# Transformation matrix for two rotations

Tags: geometry, rotations

If I am required to compute the full transformation matrix compromising of the following sequence of operations:

- rotation by $30$ degrees about $x$-axis
- translation by $1$, $-1$, $4$ in $x$, $y$ and $z$, respectively
- rotation by $45$ degrees about $y$ axis

Can I compute the rotation, translation and rotation matrix or would I be required to compute the rotation, rotation and translation matrix?

Comment: Are you asking if you need to combine the matrices in that order? In that case, the answer is "yes." You can't just scramble their order. The results are very different.

Comment: Yeah I was asking that. However, I thought that we always had to rotate first and then translate after.

Comment: you can only change the order of operations if they are made in reference to the same axis.. but here it's not this case..

Comment: @rschwieb what if the transformation (rotation and translation) was in homogeneous plane, are they can be switched or we have to save the same order (rotate then translate)? please have a look at this:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2895624/how-to-properly-do-function-rotation

Comment: @Ahmed Did you look at even two or three simple examples? You should have no trouble at all finding that rotations and translations obviously do not always commute.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you confirmed that your question is whether or not the order of transformations in the sequence has to be kept.

The answer is "yes, it does."  Rotations do not always commute with translations, so it would be disastrous to scramble their order.

Since this question has been lingering for a long time, I decided to create an answer. I had to make some assumptions since you were not completely specific as to the directions of your rotations. In your case we have (using affine $4\times 4$ matrices acting on the left of column vectors)

- $\begin{bmatrix}
  1 &0&0&0\\
  0&\sqrt{3}/2&-1/2 &0\\
  0&1/2 &\sqrt{3}/2 &0\\
  0&0&0&1
  \end{bmatrix}$  (counterclockwise 30 degrees around x)
- $\begin{bmatrix}
  1 &0&0&1\\
  0&1&0 &-1\\
  0&0 &1 &4\\
  0&0&0&1
  \end{bmatrix}$ (add $(1,-1,4)$ to the x,y,z components)
- $\begin{bmatrix}
  \sqrt{2}/2&0&-\sqrt{2}/2 &0\\
  0 &1&0&0\\
  \sqrt{2}/2&0 &\sqrt{2}/2 &0\\
  0&0&0&1
  \end{bmatrix}$ (counterclockwise rotation around $y$)

Multiplying them in the order they are applied, (if the matrices above are $A,B,C$, then that order is $CBA$ in my notation) that makes a final transformation of

$\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{2}/2&-\sqrt{2}/4&-\sqrt{6}/4&-3\sqrt{2}/2\\
0&\sqrt{3}/2&-1/2&-1\\
\sqrt{2}/2&\sqrt{2}/4&\sqrt{6}/4&5\sqrt{2}/2\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$

With the same matrices, one can see that changing the order of multiplication changes this final transformation.